# JPA Join with childEntity.childForeignEntity

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistence

*I do not know how it is called in one word, but let me explain in details.*

Lets assume I have following tables/schema in my database:

[image: DB Sample]

And following classes accordingly:

1.Post

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "post")
    private Set<PostComment> postComments = new HashSet<>();
}
```

2.Post Comments

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post_comments")
public class PostComment {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "post_id")
    private Long postId;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="post_id")
    private Post post;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

3.User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "some_attributes")
    private String someAttributes;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<PostComment> postComments = new HashSet<>();
}
```

How can I join Post with User via PostComment, so in my Post entity I could get all users commented:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post {
    ....
    
    //@ join with post_comments.user_id
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, just get `PostComment.user` where `PostComment.post` equals your post.

```
@Query("select pc.user from PostComment pc where pc.post = :post")
List<User> getUsersWithComments(@Param("post") Post post);
```

Seems to work for me. Gives me the following SQL:

```
Hibernate: select user1_.id as id1_2_, user1_.some_attributes as some_att2_2_ from post_comments postcommen0_ inner join users user1_ on postcommen0_.user_id=user1_.id where postcommen0_.post_id=?
```

I don't know what this is all about:

```
@Column(name = "post_id")
private Long postId;

@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long userId;
```

or this

```
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
@JoinColumn(name="post_id")
```

and you shouldn't do this:

```
 = new HashSet<>();
```

and while we're at it this is redundant.

```
fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
```

Comment: It is crucial for me to have @Query on entity field, is this possible?